# How much RealTime is Elasticsearch, Solr and DSE realtime search?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch, datastax-enterprise

From some last couple of weeks, I have been working around Elasticsearch and Solr, and trying to do OLTP processing in real time. However, what comes to me is they claims(especially ES) to be real time. The meaning of real time looks a lot fuzzy to me.

If we go deep into it, both ES and Solr, defines a refresh rate or a soft-commit rate, after which the newly indexed documents would be available for search, effectively providing only Near-Real time capabilities.

It looks like by Real time search, it is either a marketing statement to call it real time, or they make the word fuzzy by talking about Real Time Search rather than batch or analytical processing.

Am I correct, or correct me if I am wrong, and there is a real-time search possible in a typical OLTP system, where every transaction has search visibility to last document ?

Answer (score 6):

Elasticsearch is a Near Real Time search engine for search. Elasticsearch is Real Time for operations like Create, Update, Delete and Get.

By default, refresh is 1 second. In some use cases, it could appear as real time. For example, I was working for a french gov service and we were producing statistics per day. So for our use case, it was somehow real time from our perspective.

For logs for example, 1 second is enough in most use cases.

You can modify this default value but it comes with a cost.

If you really need real time, then you probably want to use a SQL database.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, DSE Search is indeed Near real-time and has not yet achieved the mythical goal of absolute zero latency. But... even traditional Real real-time is not real-time once you factor in the time to do the actual database update, plus the fact that a lot of traditional database updates are batch-oriented, or even if the actual update operation is not batched, there is likely to be some human process that delays the start of the database update from the original source of a data change.

Also keep in mind that the latency of a database update needs to include maintaining the required (tunable) consistency for replicating data updates in the cluster.

Rather than push you back towards SQL if you want real-time, I would challenge you to fully justify the true latency requirements of the app. For example, with complex distributed applications you need to be prepared for occasional resource outages, such as network delays, so that it is usually much better to design a modern distributed application to be a lot more flexible and asynchronous than a traditional, synchronous, fragile (think HealthCare.gov) app architecture that improperly depends on a perception of zero-latency distributed operations.

Finally, we are working on enhancements to reduce the actual latency of database updates, coupled with ongoing improvements in hardware performance that further shrink the update latency window.

But ultimately, all computing real-time measures will have some non-zero latency and modern distributed apps must be designed for at least some degree of decoupling between database updates and absolute dependency on those updates.

Worst case scenario, apps that need to synchronize with database updates may need to implement a polling strategy to wait for the update to complete.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch has real time features for CRUD operations. On GET operations, it checks the Transaction log, to look for any uncommitted changes and return the most relevant document.

The Percolator feature enables realtime in search queries as well. It allows you to register queries (percolation), that will be used at indexing time to return matching documents to those predefined queries.

This workflow looks like this:

1. Register specific query (percolation) in Elasticsearch
2. Index new content (passing a flag to trigger percolation)
3. The response to the indexing operation will contain the matched percolations

A very good blog with live example that explains the Percolator concept:

http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsesarch-percolator